# how to use Storage Access Framework in a simple file upload code Button?

Tags: android, button, upload, filechooser, storage-access-framework

I'm new to android and I want to upload a file using Storage Access Framework to make users able to choose a file from it, what is the best simple way to do that and how? thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across these open source libraries just recently myself...

```
 https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

 https://github.com/ianhanniballake/LocalStorage

 https://github.com/spacecowboy/NoNonsense-FilePicker
```

These resources should definitely lead you towards your solution.